# Storing a large hash on HDD

Tags: c, linux, storage, hashtable

I am trying to store a simple large hashtable (64it key, 64bit value) about 80Gb in size on a hard drive. What is the most efficient way to do it if I want to get best performance?

Keys to look up are totally random and I have to look up every 10ms? Is there an abstraction available as a C/Linux library which can map/hash the key to Logical Block Address of HDD so that access will be faster?

Please give some guidelines.

Comment: I don't know how to get best performance, but storing to key-value stores such as Berkley DB or Redis, would be sufficient for most cases. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#Key-value_stores

Comment: Are the lookups sequencial, or can you batch up. Desktop drives have an avg. seek time in the 10 ms range, so you would need to get your record from disk with one read. Or use something that don,t imvolve moving parts.

Comment: Given it's such a large amount of data, is there a reason that you're not simply using a database, which would give you all the features of optimization and scalability?

Comment: Caches and even more so external storage (HDD) are arch enemies to "totally random". Unless the complete working set fits into RAM or you can predict which keys will be looked up next in some way or you can prefetch key N+1 while you process item N you are at loss. That said, in some cases a hash table is not the smartest choice for that exact reason of "totally random acess with guaranteed misses". Depending on your access pattern an [algorithmically slower structure](http://cr.yp.to/critbit.html) may be much faster due to better access pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You might use a memory mapped file (`mmap`), and then arange your data in such a way that you would only read one page for each lookup. This could be done by having all keys sorted in the file, and then have an in memory index that holds the first key of each page.

Answer (score 0):

Rely on the file system to do the work, and use the hash to form a file system path & file name.  E.g., at 64 bits, assume your key, in 16 hex characters, is

`5a5bf28dcd794499`

Store that hash's value in file \5a\5b\f2\8d\cd\79\44\99.txt

This scheme only loads each subdirectory with a max of 256 folders/files.  Git does this, but only goes one directory deep, probably assuming (reasonably) that you won't commit billions of files to your git store.

Answer (score 0):

Some general guidelines:

- Use open addressing with linear probing to resolve collisions. This should result in at most a single HDD access per lookup.
- On a 64-bit system, try `mmap`ing the file for better cache performance.
- It might help to create a separate partition and access it directly via `/dev/sd??`.